# Treating a case class as a product for the purposes of mzero

Tags: scala, scalaz

With Scalaz 7, we can get the zero for products of monoids:

```
scala> mzero[(Int, String)]
res13: (Int, String) = (0,"")
```

Is there an easier way to get the zero for a case class whose fields are monoids? Ideally one that doesn't require repeating the types of the fields à la:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)
defined class Foo
scala> (Foo.apply _).tupled(mzero[(Int, String)])
res15: Foo = Foo(0,)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in Shapeless you'd need some boilerplate, like this:

```
implicit def fooIso = Iso.hlist(Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)
```

We can do something similar in Scalaz 7 (although much less elegantly). First for some general machinery:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Isomorphism._

case class MonoidFromIsorphism[F, G](iso: F <=> G)(
  implicit val G: Monoid[G]
) extends IsomorphismMonoid[F, G]
```

Now we can write:

```
case class Foo(x: Int, y: String)

implicit object fooMonoid extends MonoidFromIsorphism(
  new IsoSet[Foo, (Int, String)] {
    def to = (Foo.unapply _) andThen (_.get)
    def from = (Foo.apply _).tupled
  }
)
```

Which works:

```
scala> mzero[Foo]
res0: Foo = Foo(0,)
```

This approach still requires you to repeat the types, and it's not much more concise than just writing out the instance for `Foo` by hand (actually it's less concise if you count the `MonoidFromIsomorphism` definition, but that feels to me like the convenient sort of thing that really ought to be in the library).

What's missing is the `HList`-tuple isomorphism that would allow us just to write a simple `Foo`-`HList` isomorphism, like in Shapeless. `scalaz.typelevel` doesn't (currently) provide this out of the box, but it shouldn't be too hard to implement, following Shapeless as a model.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a monoid for it.

```
implicit val fooMonoid = new Monoid[Foo] {
  def zero = Foo(mzero[Int], mzero[String])
  def append(f1: Foo, f2: => Foo) = Foo(Monoid[Int].append(f1.x,f2.x), Monoid[String].append(f1.y,f2.y))
}
```

There is probably a better way to write the impl, but thats the basic idea.

I guess with macros we could define it for case classes in general.

Comment: Yeah, I've settled for defining them explicitly for now; it just feels like there should be a better way. I'll accept this if nothing better comes along.

Comment: Aparently the typelevel stuff can do it in scalaz. I'm having trouble making it work.

Comment: shapeless also does it - https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/monoids.scala

Comment: Can also write that append in a slightly more pleasing way:
def append(f1: Foo, f2: => Foo) = Foo(f1.x |+| f2.x, f1.y |+| f2.y)